# show image in picture gallery in windows phone 7

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, binding, picturegallery

I have an image app in wp7.

```
class Images
{
   public string Title {get;set;}
   public string Path {get;set;}
}
```

on page level, i bind title and path(relative to my app) it to a list.

What i need is, when user click on list item the respective image open in picture gallery of windows phone 7.

Answer (score 0):

You should clarify your question, but I suppose `Path` is the location of your image in isolated storage. Providing that `Image` is the name of your Image in xaml

```
img.Source = GetImage(LoadIfExists(image.Path));
```

`LoadIfExists` returns the binary data for a file in Isolated Storage, and GetImage returns it as a `WriteableBitmap` :

```
    public static WriteableBitmap GetImage(byte[] buffer)
    {
        int width = buffer[0] * 256 + buffer[1];
        int height = buffer[2] * 256 + buffer[3];

        long matrixSize = width * height;

        WriteableBitmap retVal = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);

        int bufferPos = 4;

        for (int matrixPos = 0; matrixPos < matrixSize; matrixPos++)
        {
            int pixel = buffer[bufferPos++];
            pixel = pixel << 8 | buffer[bufferPos++];
            pixel = pixel << 8 | buffer[bufferPos++];
            pixel = pixel << 8 | buffer[bufferPos++];
            retVal.Pixels[matrixPos] = pixel;
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    public static byte[] LoadIfExists(string fileName)
    {
        byte[] retVal;

        using (IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (iso.FileExists(fileName))
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = iso.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    retVal = new byte[stream.Length];
                    stream.Read(retVal, 0, retVal.Length);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                retVal = new byte[0];
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

If you want to write the image into the Picture Library, it's basically the same process, ending by calling `SavePictureToCameraRoll()` of `MediaLibrary` as explained on this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769549%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: i have images in folder of my application, say images\image1.png, images\image2.png ,etc. i want these images to open in picture gallery so that user can play with the image as in picture gallery

Comment: I've updated my answer. The "folder" in you application is called Isolated Storage, so my original answer fits to load this image. The Picture Gallery is called Picture Library by Microsoft, my update links to an article from MSDN giving all you need. You can't however launch the Pictures app from within your App.